# iOS 9 setTimeout() issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I want to act the distance traveled by a user with JS. The following works on chrome in mobile mode, but when I switch over to iOS, nothing works. I did a bit of digging and found there was something special about setTimeout() on mobile, although the given solution did not work. If I remove the setTimeout(), everything works on iOS, but it fires too fast for it to register good movement.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){


var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
var statusdiv = document.getElementById('statusdiv');
var startx = 0;
var starty = 0;
var dist = 0;

box1.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });

box1.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){

    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];

    startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX);
    starty = parseInt(touchobj.clientY);

    setTimeout(function(){

        var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - startx,2) + Math.pow(parseInt(touchobj.clientY) - starty,2));
        var angleDeg = 180 - Math.atan2((parseInt(touchobj.clientY) - starty) , (parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - startx)) * (180 / Math.PI);
        statusdiv.innerHTML = 'Status: touchmove<br> Horizontal distance traveled: ' + dist + 'px';

    } , 50);

    e.preventDefault();

}, false)


}, false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't clean this as much as I wanted, but it works. I switched it so it works on an interval instead.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){


function calc(){
    var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - startx,2) + Math.pow(parseInt(touchobj.clientY) - starty,2));
    var angleDeg = 180 - Math.atan2((parseInt(touchobj.clientY) - starty) , (parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - startx)) * (180 / Math.PI);
    statusdiv.innerHTML = 'Status: touchmove<br> Horizontal distance traveled: ' + dist + 'px';

    startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX);
    starty = parseInt(touchobj.clientY);
}

var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
var statusdiv = document.getElementById('statusdiv');
var startx = 0;
var starty = 0;
var dist = 0;
var intThing;
var touchobj;

box1.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ 

    intThing = setInterval(calc, 50);
    e.preventDefault(); 

});

box1.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){

    touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];

    e.preventDefault();

}, false)

box1.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){ 

    clearInterval(intThing);
    e.preventDefault(); 

});


}, false)
```